# Maximum the result from multiple functions which share an input amount

Tags: algorithm, optimization, max

[image]

I have multiple functions as shown in the image. For a fixed x value, I need to distribute it into f, g, and h functions for getting the maximum output (y). In other words, having a fixed x value, find a, b, and c in which these conditions are satisfied:

1. a + b + c = x
2. a >= 0 and b >= 0 and c >= 0
3. f(a) + g(b) + h(c) has max value.

Given the functions are continuous and monotonic. How should I write code to find out a, b, and c? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't that just amount to finding the function that is above the other ones at that point?

Comment: @Nelfeal No, for example, if we have x = +infinite, then probably f(x) will yield the best result. But if x is small then h(x) will be the best. If x is in the middle, then f(x/3) + g(x/3) + h(x/3) probably yields better result than either f(x), g(x), or h(x) alone.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74139076/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154805/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under appropriate assumptions, if the maximum has a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0, then a necessary condition is f'(a) = g'(b) = h'(c). Intuitively, if one of these derivatives was greater than the others, then we could effect an improvement by increasing the corresponding variable a little bit and decreasing another variable by the same amount. Otherwise, the maximum has a = 0 or b = 0 or c = 0, and we have a lower dimensional problem of the same type.

The algorithm is to loop over all seven possibilities for whether a, b, c are zero (assuming x > 0 to avoid the trivial case), then solve the equations a + b + c = x and f'(a) = g'(b) = h'(c) (omitting the variables that are zero) to find the candidate solutions, then return the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you only had 2 functions f and g, you would be looking for the x that maximises the maximum of a :-> f(a) + g(x-a) on [0,x], which is a sum of an increasing and a decreasing function, so you can't have any guarantee about it.

Still if these functions are given to you as closed form expressions, you can compute u(a)=f(a)+g(x-a) and try to find the maximum (under sufficient assumptions, you will have u'(a) = 0 and u''(a) <= 0 for instance).

Going back to the 3 functions case, if it's possible you can compute for every a, v(a) = max_{b in [0, x-a]} ( g(b)+h(x-a-b) ), and then compute the max of (f+v)(a), or do with b or c first if it works better, but in the general case there is no efficient algorithm.